# data in combobox are filled with data in database

Tags: php, database

```
function dropDownStudent()
{
    $connect = connect();
    $sql = "SELECT lastname, firstname, middleinitial FROM student";
    $sql_connect = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
}

<?php
include("process.php");
```

?>

```
<?php
            $result = dropDownStudent();
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){?>
            <select name = "stud" required>
                <? echo "<option> value='".$row['id']"'>" . $row['lastname'] . "," . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['middleinitial'] . "</option>";?>
            </select>
            <?php
            }
```

?>

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\capstone\registerstudent.php on line 11
>
> i dont know why this is my error. i donw know my parameter 1 is null

Answer (score 0):

In your Function you nee to return the result. Otherwise `$result` will be `null` and therefor `mysqli_fetch_array` won't work.

```
function dropDownStudent()
{
    $connect = connect();
    $sql = "SELECT lastname, firstname, middleinitial FROM student";
    return  mysqli_query($connect, $sql); // You did this wrong
}
```

---

to further improve it, you shouldn't to the connect in the function:

```
$connect = connect();
function dropDownStudent()
{
    global $connect;
    $sql = "SELECT lastname, firstname, middleinitial FROM student";
    return  mysqli_query($connect, $sql); // You did this wrong
}
```

Otherwise you will open a new connection everytime you use the function. This way it's only one connection at a time.